# How to send iSeries command from Python using QCMDEXC

Tags: python, ibm-midrange

I am trying to send a command to the iSeries (AS/400) utilizing QCMDEXC from Python.  I know I can connect to the iSeries because I can display members from QGPL:

```
src.execute('select * from qgpl/bwusrprf')
for row in src:
    print (row)
```

I have tried all combinations of syntax for the "CALL QCMDEXC" (shown below) command with no success.  Is this even possible?  Is this the correct method to issue QCMDEXC?

Python code:

```
src.execute(call qcmdexc('dspusrprf usrprf(*all) output(*outfile) outfile(qgpl/audusrprf)', 0000000061.00000)
```

======================================================================================
Error message:

```
src.execute(call qcmdexc('dspusrprf usrprf(*all) output(*outfile) outfile(qgpl/audusrprf)', 0000000061.00000)
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you using pyodbc for the connection?

Comment: You might need to make the command all upper case. You might need to add the library where DSPUSRPRF exists (QSYS).

Comment: See @JamesA's answer.  You already showed that `execute()` takes a string in your own `SELECT` example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need quotes around the entire command as follows:

```
src.execute("call qcmdexc parm('dspusrprf usrprf(*all) output(*outfile) outfile(qgpl/audusrprf)', 0000000061.00000)")
```

or better yet declare it as a string:

```
parm = "dspusrprf usrprf(*all) output(*outfile) outfile(qgpl/audusrprf)"
cmd = "call qcmdexc parm('{0:s}', {1:016.5f})".format(parm, len(parm))
src.execute(cmd)
```

Comment: Absolutely +1.  I'm not completely sure there won't be other problems after OP follows this advice, but I'm quite confident this is the first step regardless.  The argument fed to `execute()` has to be a string rather than naked code, otherwise the Python interpreter is obliged to try to parse it.  And since it's not valid Python....

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I tried all combinations of quotes and parsing. I must have missed that one.  I got one step closer.  Now I am getting a pyodbc.error.  I'll look into that and see where it leads me.  It is telling me "Extended dynamic support disabled".

Comment: Be sure to accept James' answer.  If you can't work through the new error, open a new question.  Thanks!